# Смена блока по нажатию кнопки

Tags: javascript

Кто может подсказать, вот имеется код

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
 
 
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
 
    let dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("explore_links");
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      let openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Выпадает список и при нажатии на ссылку списка, меняется содержимое блока ( код смены блока другой, думаю он роли не играет )
На 2 скриншоте сменился блок и когда нажимаю на кнопку, то выпадающее окно не работает, а стиль css применяется на кнопку ,которая была в предыдущем блоке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути тут можно запросто использовать механику *вкладок* (tabs).

Например так:

```js
let tabsContent = document.querySelector('.tabs-content'),
    select = document.querySelector('.select');
    
select.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('select__drop-item')) {
    let id = e.target.getAttribute('data-id') || false,
        item = tabsContent.querySelector('.tabs-content__item[data-id="'+id+'"]');
    if(item && !item.classList.contains('-active')) {
      tabsContent.querySelector('.tabs-content__item.-active').classList.remove('-active');
      item.classList.add('-active');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.tabs-content > .tabs-content__item:not(.-active){
  display: none;
}

.select {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.select__placeholder { 
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: orange;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select__drop {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  /* Чтобы список выпадал вверх, укажите вместо top - bottom */
}

.select__drop-item {
  padding: .25em 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select:hover .select__drop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div class="tabs-content__item -active" data-id="1">
    <h1>item 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-content__item" data-id="2">
    <h1>item 2</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs-content__item" data-id="3">
    <h1>item 3</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="select">
  <div class="select__placeholder">Выбрать</div>
  <div class="select__drop">
    <div class="select__drop-item" data-id="1">item 1</div>
    <div class="select__drop-item" data-id="2">item 2</div>
    <div class="select__drop-item" data-id="3">item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```